# F# linq filter column by null value

Tags: entity-framework, f#, ef-core-3.1

in F# query can't make filtering by null work

role.CompanyId is nullable column

```
query {
    for role in roles do
    where (role.CompanyId = null)
    select role
}
```

Compiler gives error `Solution api.sln
    Project Roles.Domain
      Roles\Roles.Domain\CompanyRoles\R.fs:66 The type 'Nullable<int>' does not have 'null' as a proper value. To create a null value for a Nullable type use 'System.Nullable()'.`

Can somebody help ?

Comment: Did you try `where (not role.CompanyId.HasValue)`? The error message is misleading, but it does indicate that you are dealing with `Nullable<_something_>`.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
query {
    for role in roles do
    where (role.Company = null)
    select role
}
```